# Is there any way to save registers before jumping into function?

Tags: c, assembly, visual-c++, x86-64, calling-convention

this is my first question, because I couldn't find anything related to this topic.

Recently, while making a class for my C game engine project I've found something interesting:

```
struct Stack *S1 = new(Stack);
struct Stack *S2 = new(Stack);

S1->bPush(S1, 1, 2);               //at this point
```

`bPush` is a function pointer in the structure.

So I wondered, what does operator `->` in that case, and I've discovered:

```
 mov         r8b,2                 ; a char, written to a low point of register r8
 mov         dl,1                  ; also a char, but to d this time
 mov         rcx,qword ptr [S1]    ; this is the 1st parameter of function
 mov         rax,qword ptr [S1]    ; !Why cannot I use this one?
 call        qword ptr [rax+1A0h]  ; pointer call
```

so I assume -> writes an object pointer to *rcx*, and I'd like to use it in functions (methods they shall be). So the question is, how can I do something alike

```
 push        rcx
 // do other call vars
 pop         rcx
 mov         qword ptr [this], rcx
```

before it starts writing other variables of the function. Something with preprocessor?

Comment: This is a huge topic, but the basic answer is that you *do* pass (some) parameters in registers. The concept you need to learn about is [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention).

Comment: You cannot assume that anything is going to be written to rcx.  The compiler has chosen to do so in this situation, but any change in code or compiler settings may break this.  If you want to pass this pointer to your function, pass it as an argument.

Comment: that's not correct, when using (->) rcx is always used to represent a pointer *this

Comment: And based on what are you assuming that rcx is always used? Because that's wrong, it depends on compiler and platform. Anyway, it isn't clear to me what you're asking. If you're writing inline assembly and want to save the `rcx` register, you can push and pop it yourself. If you aren't writing inline assembly, you shouldn't care what happens to individual registers.

Comment: I'd write it, but x64 doesn't allow me to

Comment: "doesn't allow"? What does that mean?

Comment: @IlyaPakhmutov C doesn't have “this.”  Did you perhaps tag the wrong language?

Comment: @fuz I did not, I'm making classes in C, but I pass *this explicitly in methods. And it has somewhat close to this, but its not shown

Comment: @interjay Complier writes that inline assembler is not supported in x64 (using VS2015)

Comment: In that case, why do you care which registers are used by the compiler?

Comment: @interjay: I think Ilya means that MSVC doesn't allow / support inline asm when targeting x86-64, only 32-bit x86.  It's not of course x86-64 that stops you from using inline asm, it's Microsoft's compiler.  Other compilers (gcc, clang, ICC) all allow GNU C inline asm syntax when targeting x86-64 Windows.  But then you have to write constraints and clobbers yourself.

Comment: for what you need save any registers before function call ?! you not need do this at all

Comment: `->` is implemented by `mov  rax,qword ptr [S1]` and the `[rax+1A0h]` addressing mode to `call`.  The rest of the instructions are implementing the `()` operator on the function pointer, following the Windows x64 calling convention.  Are you planning to write some stand-alone asm functions?  If so, see https://agner.org/optimize/ for a calling-convention guide.  If not, why are you trying to tell the compiler how to do its job (of generating asm to implement your C)?  You haven't explained why you think push/pop to save/restore RCX would be more efficient than what the compiler does.

Comment: If anything, I'd be trying to convince MSVC to use the copy of `S1` it already has in RCX as the base for the `call` addressing mode, instead of wasting an instruction to load S1 again.  I suspect you'rel looking at un-optimized code, although it's possible that MSVC has a missed optimization there.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'd like to implicitly pass *this pointer, because as shown in second asm part it does the same thing twice, yes, it is what I'm looking for, bPush is a part of a struct and it cannot be called from outside, but I have to pass the pointer S1, which it already has.

Comment: Are you *sure* this is C?  `struct Stack *S1 = new(Stack);` at global scope isn't valid unless `new()` is a `#define` macro that expands to a static initializer.  (And from your disassembly, we can see that the `S1` pointer itself has static storage, otherwise loading would use a register-based addressing mode.)  It really looks like you're using C++ features.

Comment: Also, why is the function pointer a member variable, instead of just having a regular function that takes a `Stack*` arg?  Are you emulating virtual functions so each Stack object can have different implementations?

Comment: @PeterCordes I've made my own new(), it's a wrap for malloc, which starts the constructor, connected with late binding (https://github.com/Agrael1/Veritas-3D/blob/master/ConsoleApplication5/Class.c), and yes, those are virtual methods

Comment: But how can you call it at global scope?  ISO C doesn't allow non-constant initializers for global variables.  Does MSVC allow that as an extension for C?  Anyway, it's probably confusing to use the name `new` because it's *not* the C++ operator.  (In your github it's also weird that the bare typename (`Stack`) is a global struct with a size, but I guess a simple macro like `#define alloc(T) malloc(sizeof(T))` wouldn't let you do your constructor thing.  But you could write a macro or static inline function that allocates and initializes a `Stack` and returns a pointer.

Comment: @PeterCordes it acts like C++ operator, the declarations are at New.h. I use this header, when I want to create an instance of a class, and it returns a pointer, which then goes to `const void* class`. This new is universal call to all classes in the project

Comment: Yes, I figured that out, but it's *not* C++ `new`, so it's weird and confusing to use exactly that name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you'd have an easier time (and get asm that's the same or more efficient) if you wrote in C++ so you could use language built-in support for virtual functions, and for running constructors on initialization.  Not to mention not having to manually run destructors.  You wouldn't need your `struct Class` hack.

> I'd like to implicitly pass `*this` pointer, because as shown in second asm part it does the same thing twice, yes, it is what I'm looking for, bPush is a part of a struct and it cannot be called from outside, but I have to pass the pointer S1, which it already has.

**You get inefficient asm because you disabled optimization.**

MSVC `-O2` or `-Ox` doesn't reload the static pointer twice.  It does waste a `mov` instruction copying between registers, but if you want better asm use a better compiler (like gcc or clang).

The oldest MSVC on the Godbolt compiler explorer is CL19.0 from MSVC 2015, which compiles this source

```
struct Stack {
    int stuff[4];
    void (*bPush)(struct Stack*, unsigned char value, unsigned char length);
};


struct Stack *const S1 = new(Stack);

int foo(){
    S1->bPush(S1, 1, 2);

    //S1->bPush(S1, 1, 2);
    return 0;  // prevent tailcall optimization
}
```

**[into this asm (Godbolt)](https://godbolt.org/z/jXvvg0)**

```
# MSVC 2015  -O2
int foo(void) PROC                                        ; foo, COMDAT
$LN4:
        sub     rsp, 40                             ; 00000028H
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR Stack * __ptr64 __ptr64 S1
        mov     r8b, 2
        mov     dl, 1
        mov     rcx, rax                   ;; copy RAX to the arg-passing register
        call    QWORD PTR [rax+16]
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 40                             ; 00000028H
        ret     0
int foo(void) ENDP                                        ; foo
```

(I compiled in C++ mode so I could write `S1 = new(Stack)` without having to copy your github code, and write it at global scope with a non-constant initializer.)

Clang7.0 `-O3` loads into `RCX` straight away:

```
# clang -O3
foo():
        sub     rsp, 40
        mov     rcx, qword ptr [rip + S1]
        mov     dl, 1
        mov     r8b, 2
        call    qword ptr [rcx + 16]          # uses the arg-passing register
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 40
        ret
```

Strangely, clang only decides to use low-byte registers when targeting the Windows ABI with `__attribute__((ms_abi))`.  It uses `mov esi, 1` to avoid false dependencies when targeting its default Linux calling convention, not `mov sil, 1`.

---

Or if you are using optimization, then it's because even older MSVC is even worse.  In that case you probably can't do anything in the C source to fix it, although you might try using a `struct Stack *p = S1` local variable to hand-hold the compiler into loading it into a register once and reusing it from there.)

Comment: This code is an impression, I want to find a job, but everything is already written, and in most cases writing something unique is almost impossible to do. That's why I preferred C for writing my game engine. I have no time to study 10000 frameworks and writing stuff I have hard time understanding, the best things I can give is my maze gen algorithm and C with asm. I just thing it's not going to give me an opportunity to work at Gamedev. Thanks to thee for the answer :)

Comment: @IlyaPakhmutov: I didn't mean you should use some existing library in C++, **the language itself literally has those features (virtual functions and constructors) built in to the core language**, without the standard library.  Besides, you're already using one C++ feature: non-constant static initializers (for global `S1`).  See https://godbolt.org/z/M_dCTH for the error messages if you compile that with C compilers, not C++.  (I mocked up your `new` macro with a prototype for a function that takes a `void*` and returns a `void*`, casting the result so it is valid C++.)

Comment: S1 is not global, it's inside main(), and I didn't list it on git, I've launched it on 2 compliers - MSVC and GCC, and both in -C; new is not macro, it's regular function, yes it takes void* and also arguments for the constructor.

Comment: @IlyaPakhmutov: if it's inside `main`, then how can the asm addressing mode for it be `qword ptr [S1]`?  Is it `static`?  If not, it will be stored on the stack (or optimized away), and there won't be a symbol with that name in the asm.  Did you hand-edit the asm to replace `[rsp + 40]` with `[S1]` or something?

Comment: nope, it's just Visual Studio gave me that beautiful Disassembly code listing. Idk, maybe it is its feature but x86 gives me this:
`S1->bPush(S1, 1, 2);
 mov         esi,esp  
 push        2  
 push        1  
 mov         eax,dword ptr [S1]  
 push        eax  
 mov         ecx,dword ptr [S1]  
 mov         edx,dword ptr [ecx+170h]  
 call        edx  `

Comment: @IlyaPakhmutov: MSVC's asm output does define asm constants for the offsets relative to the stack frame.  e.g. `S1$ = 32` before the function, then it uses  `QWORD PTR S1$[rsp]` inside the function (https://godbolt.org/z/eHgkip).  Maybe MSVC2010 was different and defined `S1 equ rbp+40` or something (for a text substitution)?  But that would be weird.  Anyway, as you can see in that case, with optimization enabled compilers keep the return value from `new` in a call-preserved register and simply use it.